# No PolySpatial option under 'window', project settings xr says there's no VisionOS plugins in XR Plug-In Management either

Tags: unity, applevision

I'm running Unity 2022.3.20f1 and can't find any polyspatial options anywhere.

I've gone through start up guides and Unity's official videos but nothing aobut why the options wouldn't be here..

[image]

[image]